# Migrating Openlayers 2 BBOX strategy to Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm migrating a map applications from Openlayers 2 into ol3 and had a bbox layer which fired a request to the server when the extent changes. I use the refresh strategy (with force: true) and the server returns an array of objects I process using a custom format.

```
var refreshStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh({
  force: true
});

OpenLayers.Format.GTFS = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Format, {
  read: function(body) {
    var stops = JSON.parse(body), point, features = [];

    for(var i=0,l=stops.length; i<l; i++) {
      point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(stops[i].stop_lon, stops[i].stop_lat);
      features.push(new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point, stops[i]));
    }
    return features;
    }
});

var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('Stops', {
  projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'),
  visibility: true,
  strategies: [
    new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX({resFactor: 1.2}),
    refreshStrategy
    ],
  protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GTFS(),
    url: '/api/v1/stops.json'
  })
});

refreshStrategy.activate();
```

It appears `ol.source.Vector` supports only a single strategy. I  tried using just the bbox strategy but the feature markers flicker and data get's reloaded every time I pan

```
var stopFeatures = new ol.Collection();

var source = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: stopFeatures,
    loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
        extent = ol.extent.applyTransform(extent, ol.proj.getTransform("EPSG:3857", "EPSG:4326"));
        var url = '/api/stops.json?bbox=' + extent.join(',');
        $http.get(url).then(function (res) {
            var features = _.map(res.data, function (stop) {
                var stopFeature = new ol.Feature(stop);
                stopFeature.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([stop.stop_lon,stop.stop_lat],
                    'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')));
                return stopFeature;
            });
            stopFeatures.clear();
            stopFeatures.extend(features);
        });
    },
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
});
```

The clearing and resetting of the feature collection feels like I'm doing something wrong and the refresh appears to be slower.

Is `map.on('moveend',...` the way to go at implementing this on ol3?

Comment: Actually `ol.loadingstrategy.bbox` in OpenLayers 3.x does exactly the same thing as `OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX` in OpenLayers 2. What makes you think it's a "different monster"?

Comment: @ahocevar I read the code and understand what you mean. What is obscure to me is how ol2 was merging data from subsequent requests under the hood and now I've had to use a feature collection. I'm clearing features which are likely to be reinserted and I think that is probably causing it to be slower. Anyhow thanks for paying attention to this, I've added a lot more details.

Answer (score 1):

You are right - you should not be calling `clear()` and `extend()` on the feature collection. Instead, you should have something like a unique id for each feature in your JSON. If you don't, you could use a hash created from latitude and longitude. Once you have an id, use `stopFeature.setId(id)` to set the id on the feature. Then simply call `source.addFeatures(features)`. The strategy will internally compare feature ids to ids of existing features, and only insert those features with ids that are not in the source already.

Comment: Setting the ids looks better. The missing part of the port is the **refresh strategy** part. On the old map, zooming in triggers a request and actually loads more features because the server retrieves a limited amount and the smaller bbox implies new ones show up. ol3 has a singular `strategy` attribute while ol2 had an array argument.